# Font icon display issue in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, icons

The icon doesn't display in the center in my Firefox, but it is work in Opera.

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.link {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 3px;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}

i {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
    <a href="#" class="link">
        <i class='bx bx-home'></i>
    </a>
```

Have you had the below problem in your Firefox?

[This one is screenshot from Opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0aHw.png)

[And this one is Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVdYW.png)

===================Edit===================

[run code snippet in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV2Bc.png)

[run code snippet in Opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkWCO.png)

The version of my Firefox is `95.0.2` (lastest version at the moment).

How can I fix this in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your issue sadly, something I would suggest however is open both browsers side by side, open your dev tools, open elements and then you can check the css properties to check something isn't been added or missing in firefox, you may need some firefox specifc styling to resolve the issue.

Personally I haven't worked with `place-items` but checking on caniuse.com it doesn't look like it should be causing you any issues. But it might be worth running through all of your html/css to see if you're using anything thats unsupported by the version of firefox you're using.

https://caniuse.com/?search=place-items